# got 404 in word 2010 hyperlinks, but works after converting to pdf

Tags: hyperlink, http-status-code-404, ms-office, word-2010

After creating a hyperlink in MS Word 2010, I still get an error that the site cannot be opened (office error message). But if I copy the hyperlink to IE, Chrome, FF or convert the docx to a pdf the hyperlink is working.

Why?
And what can I do to let MS Word 2010 open the hyperlinks correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The site, I want to link to uses SSO and that doesn't work out of the box.
You have to use the Registry and Navigate, in order to your  Office Version (32 or 64 Bit) to:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\9.0\Common\Internet
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\9.0\Common\Internet
```

and add a DWORD named **ForceShellExecute** with value **1**.

That works!